# Lock sub UIView's to the topLayoutGuide

Tags: ios, uitableview, uiscrollview, uikit, autolayout

I have a view that extends underneath the `UINavigationBar`. This view has a subview (**MrSubview**) that should sit below the navigation bar. When I animate the `UINavigationBar` away the controllers `topLayoutGuide` will change. In this case I want **MrSubview** to move up.

My first thought was that I need to give `UIView` the `topLayoutGuide` so it can use it in an auto layout, but I guess the view should not be coupled to the controller.

I am looking for the best way to do this.

How does `UITableView` and `UIScrollView` do this?

Answer (score 0):

`UIScrollView` (`UITableView` is a subclass of `UIScrollView`) does this with the `contentInset` property. `UIViewController` can handle this automatically for you if your `view` property is a `UIScrollView`.

You pretty much have to implement this yourself in your `UIViewController` during `viewWillLayoutSubviews` if your controller's `view` property is not a scroll view.

Comment: Looks like I will have to switch to a UIScrollView. I can easily use the topLayoutGuide in an auto layout in a controller but I can use that in a UIScrollView. Can you think of a better way than adjusting a vertical space constraint in the viewWillLayoutSubviews? I would like to do it using only autolayout.

Comment: I do it using only auto layout by keeping a reference to the top constraints and updating their `constant` value during `viewWillLayoutSubviews`.

Comment: But this is not using only auto layout. It is also requires code in each view controller that uses the view.